# separate special characters from numbers in string in php

Tags: php, string, special-characters

I have `$value = "10,120,152"` in string, now i want to put each number in separate variable like `$a = 10; $b = 120; $c = 152;`
so basically what i am asking is that how to separate `,` from the numbers in a string.

Comment: Look at extract(), but I highly discourage it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the separator is always a `,` than using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) makes sense. If the separator varies though you could use a regex.

```
$value = "10,120,152";
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $value, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 120
    [2] => 152
)
```

Demo: https://eval.in/483906

That `\d+` is all continuos numbers.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/rP2bV1/1

A third approach would be using [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$value = "10,120,152";
$numbers = str_getcsv($value, ',');
print_r($numbers);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 120
    [2] => 152
)
```

Demo: https://eval.in/483907

Answer (score 0):

```
$exploded = explode("," , $values);
var_dump($exploded);
```

[Explode(string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ])](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode(), it will return an array with the numbers.

```
$array = explode(',', $value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one using [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
$value = "10,120,152";
$variables = explode("," , $values);
$variables = array_map('intval', $variables);//If you want integers add this line
list($a, $b, $c) = $variables;
```